# Partition a USB stick programmatically under Linux

Tags: linux, usb, disk-partitioning

After deleting the partitions from a USB stick and then re-inserting the disk I see the following from `dmesg`:

```
[99341.658055] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 15771720 512-byte logical blocks: (8.07 GB/7.52 GiB)
[99341.658670] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[99341.658678] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[99341.658684] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[99341.668175] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[99341.668187]  sdb
```

Now how do I create a partition /dev/sdb1 of the full size of the disk from the command line?

`fdisk` and `parted` ask stupid questions like the start and end of partition. I want the partition simply to full the entire disk. Most people I know resort to using `gparted`, which I don't want. I just want a simple one liner to create a full sized partition.

The next command I probably want to run after creating the partition is `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use [`sfdisk`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sfdisk), just omit the partition size and start.

Comment: yes `sudo sfdisk /dev/sdb` and pressing enter a lot of times seems to work!

Answer (score 5):

```
parted -s /dev/sdb mkpart primary 0% 100%
```

Answer (score 3):

I've previously scripted fdisk like:

```
echo "
n
p
1
...
" | fdisk /dev/sdb
```

Note when creating partitions on usb keys align on 1MB. Other wise performance can be affected.

Answer (score 2):

The [parted](http://linux.die.net/man/8/parted) program has an option:

> `-s, --script` - never prompt the user.

That ought to make it easier to script.